# Configuring the fetch attempt duration when EHCache attempts to connect to a Terracotta server that is down

Tags: ehcache, terracotta

if I try to connect to a Terracotta server that is currently down by calling `net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create();`, EHCache keeps retrying connection attempts for a full 300 seconds before throwing an exception with this message:

> Could not fetch configuration data from the server at 'terracottahost:9510'.  Fetch attempt duration: 300 seconds.

Is there any way to modify this time to be maybe 30 or 60 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was posted to me on the Terracotta forums by (I think) their developer:

Unfortunately that timeout looks like it is hard coded. I encourage you to open a feature request to allow it to be configurable.

So it would seem that this is not configurable after all.